# How to convert std::string to any of several types in constructor?

Tags: c++

I have the following class template which has a member variable whose type is determined by the template argument.  I want to initialize the value of this member in the constructor, which only takes a `std::string`.  Thus, my problem is that I need to convert `std::string` to any of several types (`int`, `double`, `bool`, `string`).  I don't think I can specialize just the constructor, and I would rather not specialize the entire class for each type.  The problem with my code below is that `stringstream` stops streaming out when it hits a space:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template <typename Ty>
struct Test
{
    Ty value;

    Test(string str) {
        stringstream ss;
        ss.str(str);
        ss >> value;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Test<int> t1{"42"};
    Test<double> t2{"3.14159"};
    Test<string> t3{"Hello world"};

    cout << t1.value << endl << t2.value << endl << t3.value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
42
3.14159
Hello
```

instead of "Hello world".  Is there some way to get `stringstream` to not stop at whitespace, or some other device that will do arbitrary conversions like I need?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at [Boost.Lexical_Cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Just declare a special implementation before the generalized implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
struct Test {
    T value;
    Test(std::string);
};

template<>
inline Test<std::string>::Test(std::string str) {
    value = str;
}

template<typename T>
inline Test<T>::Test(std::string str) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str(str);
    ss >> value;
}

int main() {
    Test<int> t1{"42"};
    Test<double> t2{"3.14159"};
    Test<std::string> t3{"Hello world"};

    std::cout
        << t1.value << std::endl
        << t2.value << std::endl
        << t3.value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is an [ideone](http://ideone.com/VSoAzQ) working example.

Comment: Hey, this works.  I didn't know you could specialize the constructor without specializing the whole class.  The key is not defining the constructor in the class at all; the general case and the specializations all go outside.  On a side note, as a consequence of specializing outside of the class, I had to mark both versions of my constructor `inline` to avoid multiple definition errors.

Comment: If it's defined in a header, yes you need to do that. I'll update my answer. Also realized that some compilers require `template<>` (perhaps with C++ 14) before the specialized definition, so updating that too

Comment: Yes, GCC 4.9.3 required `template<>`.  Forgot to mention that.